# Bash - checking if user is logged via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am in the process of writing a bash script which has to do with recursive modifications of UIDs and GIDs of a given target user `T`. It has to be run on a remote machine and as root.

In order to work properly, the script requires that such user `T` is not the one which made the ssh connection. Otherwise, commands as `usermod` won't work as there are processes alive owing to `T` (ssh).

In other words, to operate on `T`, I must be logged as root after having connected as `S`.

Is there a way I can ensure that the user logged is not the target of the script? i.e. that `S!=T`?

Comment: The script would know what `T` is, right?  It can determine `S` at runtime by using `whoami`.

Comment: @devnull, thanks. The script knows `T`, nonetheless it does not `S` (I guess) as it is run by `root`. In other words, `whoami` returns `root`. `S` is used just to establish the ssh connection.

Comment: What about using `w` to figure if `T` is logged in?

Comment: How does `S` become root? `sudo`? `su`? something else?

Comment: @devnull, parsing the output of `w` looks like a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: @kojiro, at the moment brutally via `su`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the part of the script that runs before privilege escalation, keep in mind `ssh` normally sets the `USER` environment variable. You can export that to another name to keep around within the escalated environment.

```
OLD_USER=$USER su -m # the `-m` flag says to keep the current environment
```

(Then again, if you can modify the part of the script that runs before privilege escalation, why not just check if `S=T` then?)

Also, if you become root using `sudo`, that command sets `SUDO_USER` and `SUDO_UID` for you.